# how to get user's faculty in shibboleth attribute-map.xml

Tags: xml, shibboleth

I have configured a Shibboleth sp correctly but i got some problem with the user's attribute that my idp give me back. The attribute that I really need back from idp is user's department/faculty (university scenario). I have tryed to take it by adding on my attribute-map.xml file some string like:

```
<Attribute name="urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:eduPersonScopedAffiliation" id="affiliation">
    <AttributeDecoder xsi:type="ScopedAttributeDecoder" caseSensitive="false"/>
</Attribute>
<Attribute name="urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.9" id="affiliation">
    <AttributeDecoder xsi:type="ScopedAttributeDecoder" caseSensitive="false"/>
</Attribute>
```

I have readed that with affiliation i could get the faculty but seems doesn't work. 
Someone had some advice about how to get faculty value? or Should I need to contact my idp to know how to configure my sp for that attribute?

Answer (score 0):

The eduPersonScopedAffiliation attribute will only give you a broad category of user type, not their specific Department. It's made up of the eduPersonAffiliation value (eg "student" or "staff") and the security domain (eg. "somecollege.edu"). "Faculty" is a possible value of eduPersonAffiliation, not a description of the data type.

Your best bet for the specific faculty or department is something like ou (urn:oid:2.5.4.11) or eduPersonPrimaryOrgUnitDN (urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.8).

However, institutions implement attributes in their own ways for various reasons. I'd recommend contacting your IdP admin for advice, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Thank for your answer to my question. I will try to add that attribute.